# Ubuntu boot failure on AMD threadripper 3960X CPU

Tags: boot, system-installation, amd-ryzen

I recently assembled a machine with the AMD threadripper 3960X 24-core CPU on a MSI TRX40 PRO WiFi Motherboard. Now I'm able to boot a Windows 10 disk on it, however for Ubuntu I cannot even boot from a Ubuntu installation USB disk. I tried versions of 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04, but neither works.

I also tried booting an existing ubuntu 18.04 disk, but got weird errors

[image]

I've seen some posts like this one: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-3700x-3900x-linux&num=1

But still not very clear what to do in my case. Thanks for the leads.

---

Update: When trying the USB installation stick, it always goes into the checking file mode

[image]

and no matter whether I skip or not, it goes into the Ubuntu loading screen and freeze. After a while, it just gives all black screen.

Comment: With a very new system, you need latest kernel, drivers & support files. Minimum would then be 20.04.1 and even then you may need further updates. Do not even try old distributions like 16.04 or even 18.04.

Comment: I am facing similar issues with the same motherboard and CPU. Did you manage to find out what is wrong, so that Ubuntu fails to install?